# Regex in javascript complex

Tags: javascript, regex

string `str` contains somewhere within it `http://www.example.com/` followed by 2 digits and 7 random characters (upper or lower case). One possibility is `http://www.example.com/45kaFkeLd` or `http://www.example.com/64kAleoFr`. So the only certain aspect is that it always starts with 2 digits.

I want to retrieve "64kAleoFr".

`var url = str.match([regex here]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you’re looking for is `/[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{7}/`.

```
var string = 'http://www.example.com/64kAleoFr',
    match = (string.match(/[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{7}/) || [''])[0];
console.log(match); // '64kAleoFr'
```

Note that on the second line, I use the [good old `.match()` trick](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/match-trick/) to make sure no `TypeError` is thrown when no match is found. Once this snippet has executed, `match` will either be the empty string (`''`) or the value you were after.

Comment: Nice use of the match trick, but doesn't the url need to be in the regex too? The question said it would be contained within a larger string, so presumably it is at least possible that the larger string may have "99aAaAaAa" in it somewhere before the actual url.

Comment: @nnnnnn The question also says “So the only certain aspect is that it always starts with 2 digits.” — which leads me to believe there may be different domain names being used. There’s simply not enough information in the original question to give a complete answer. That said, it’s easy enough to prepend the domain name to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var url = str.match(/\d{2}.{7}$/)[0];
```

where:

```
\d{2} //two digits
.{7} //seven characters
$    //end of the string
```

if you don't know if it will be at the end you could use

```
 var url = str.match(/\/\d{2}.{7}$/)[0].slice(1); //grab the "/" at the begining and slice it out
```

Comment: @AnthonyNewman just in case you wanted to know, the fiddle returns undefined because you're alerting the position 1 of the array, and javascript arrays are zero based. So, `alert(matches[0]);` works fine

Answer (score 0):

what about using split ?

```
alert("http://www.example.com/64kAleoFr".split("/")[3]);
```

Comment: Question says the url will be somewhere in the middle of a longer string, so presumably there could be other "/" characters earlier in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`http://www\\.example\\.com/([0-9]{2}\\w{7})` this is your pattern. You'll get your 2 digits and 7 random characters in group 1.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the full-stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/",
    re = new RegExp(url.replace(/\./g,"\\.") + "(\\d{2}[A-Za-z]{7})");

str = "This is a string with a url: http://www.example.com/45kaFkeLd in the middle.";

var code = str.match(re);

if (code != null) {
    // we have a match
    alert(code[1]); // "45kaFkeLd"
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The url needs to be part of the regex if you want to avoid matching other strings of characters elsewhere in the input. The above assumes that the url should be configurable, so it constructs a regex from the `url` variable (noting that "." has special meaning in a regex so it needs to be escaped). The bit with the two numbers and seven letter is then in parentheses so it can be captured.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/NzELc/

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your example strings, both strings have few digits and a random string after a slash (/) and if the pattern is fixed then i would rather suggest you to split your string with slash and get the last element of the array which was the result of the split function.

Here is how:

```
var string = "http://www.example.com/64kAleoFr"
ar = string.split("/");
ar[ar.length - 1];
```

Hope it helps